# How do I create another LAN interface on my AP?

Tags: networking, router, lan, tomato, pfsense

My home network set up is: WAN > Pfsense router > Wireless AP with tomato firmware on it.

On my AP, I have 2 wifi networks. Home and Guest.

What I want to do is create two VLANs on my AP. I want to bridge one VLAN to my home wifi and bridge the other VLAN to my guest wifi.

My steps for this would be:

- Create Home VLAN with VID 10. Bridge it to LAN port that gets internet, br0.
- Create Guest VLAN with VID 20. Bridge it to LAN port that gets internet, br0.
- Bridge Home wifi to VID 10.
- Bridge Guest wifi to VID 20.

However, I cant. br0 is the interface for my primary LAN port. Since my AP is just an AP and not a router, my AP gets internet from my pfsense machine using the primary LAN port, not the WAN port. Well since I cant use the primary lan port interface(br0), I have to make a new Lan Bridge so I can assign it to my VLANs. And thats where I'm confused. 
It asks for an IP and a subnet for my new LAN interface.

Well br0 is 10.12.1.201 and the subnet is 255.255.255.0.

I tried to make the second LAN interface 10.12.1.250 and the subnet as 255.255.255.0. It says it overlaps with the primary interface. Well if I make a new interface outside of the subnet of my router, how would that new interface even get internet or communicate with my router?

Comment: Sounds like your firmware is too limited. Is OpenWrt available for your AP?

Comment: I dont think so. I have  netgear wndr3400v3. It seems like v1 works with it but not v3

Answer (score 0):

> Well br0 is 10.12.1.201 and the subnet is 255.255.255.0.
>   10.12.1.250 and the subnet as 255.255.255.0. It says it overlaps with the primary interface.

Its right.

10.12.1.201 /24 goes from .1.0 to .1.255
10.12.1.250 /24 goes from .1.0 to .1.255

What you're missing is your router has "a foot in every pool" or an IP for each VLAN. So you need something like:

```
VLAN 10, LAN Gateway: 10.12.1.201
VLAN 20, GUEST Gateway: 10.12.2.201
```